# What chemical can be used for getting rid of hard water spots on cars?

Tags: acid-base, cleaning

Most water spot removers available on Amazon or automotive stores are just fine abrasives which remove a small amount of your car's clearcoat every time you use them.

I'm looking for a chemical which can dissolve the water spots made out of limestone, chalk and gypsum.

Any acids suggested should not be strong enough to damage clearcoat (diluted), should not be abrasive.
Obviously I will not leave it on my car for very long, just apply, maybe rub around and rinse off with water.

I've not had any success with vinegar.

Comment: see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/117570/will-using-vinegar-harm-car-paint , who has tried an experiment.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the water spots are not limestone, chalk or gypsum, all of which are dissolvable in acid. Maybe they are mud spots, which could contain clays which adhere to the car paint.

If a toilet bowl cleaner based on citric acid (stronger acid than acetic, also a chelator) or Coke (acidic, contains phosphate) do not work quickly (without damage), perhaps an alkaline dispersing agent (like a liquid laundry soap) plus some elbow grease could diminish the visibility of the spots. Dispersing agents for clays include phosphates and anionic polymers like polysilicates (but they are typically quite alkaline - need to check damage potential).

Then, a good waterproofing (waxy) polish could make it easier to resist and remove the spots. Discovering where the spots come from (rain, splash from puddles, lawn sprayer, etc.) could help suggest what materials are present in the spots.