# Will using vinegar harm car paint?

Tags: acid-base, cleaning

After having parked my car in a newly constructed airport parking garage, I came back to find something had dripped through a crack in the ceiling of the structure and left considerably thick film on my car.  On a glass window surface, I tested soap and water, mineral spirits, two types of latex paint remover (i.e. goof off), and household chlorine bleach.  None were effective.  But plain white 5% vinegar dissolved the film if I let it soak or scrubbed on it with a cloth.

[image: car window showing places where vinegar was effective at cleaning off a film]

My question: is an acid of the strength of vinegar a risk to automotive "paint" (the top layer is probably "clear coat").

Comment: I'd try using a paper towel wet with vinegar and just stick it to the surface of the car. Then use a spay gun to give it a good squirt. I think the worse thing you can with such a coating is rub. I'd be worried about scratching the clear coat and/or paint. Take the paper towel off and rinse with water while you rub gently with your fingers.

Comment: Vinegar is not a strong enough or corrosive enough substance to damage paint and you can minimise the risk by using a cloth or sponge wet with vinegar on the glass and not spraying the whole car or leaving it in the surface for an extended period. Also, it is a good agent for removing what is almost certainly a limescale-like layer (basically a carbonate that will react with acids).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a valid question, because [acid rain has been known to damage paints](https://www.nytimes.com/1991/11/09/news/new-paint-new-cars-acid-rain-often-they-don-t-mix.html), particularly high-gloss, i.e. clear coat. Best would be to test the effect of vinegar on a hidden area, and double-check under *bright* light from different angles. Your idea to test on glass is good, because it shows how long a soak is needed.

- If it appears unaffected, rinse afterwards with a *weak* solution of baking soda or ammonia, and then rinse again with plain water to remove any remaining acid.
- If damage is slight, can car wax effect a good repair?
- If vinegar *does* damage in the test spot, you might look at various [car polishes or even cutting compounds](https://guidetodetailing.com/damage-repair/how-to-restore-faded-oxidized-paint/), and then wax (or reapply a gloss coat, which may mean refinishing a large section of bodywork to get it to match).

Answer (score 5):

### Vinegar Test: No Visible Change After Two Hours

As advised above, I decided to test vinegar on an inconspicuous spot.

First I created a pattern of exposed paint using masking tape.  The shape was just something random that I thought I could most easily recognize, even if just a slight difference in the car's finish:

[image: masking tape on part of car's exterior paint]

Then I placed vinegar-soaked cloth on the test area of the car:

[image: Vinegar soaked cloth on auto paint]

After **two hours** (which was longer than I expected the cleaning of the other parts of the car to take), I removed the cloth, rinsed the area, and finally just washed the are normally:

[image: test area of car with soapy water]

And finally took the car into various lighting conditions.  There was no detectable difference in the finish that I could see:

[image: clean and dry with no visible damage]